# select data between 2 dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with the following code:

```
    SELECT PM.PM_Eng_Name, ISNULL(SUM(PMOutput.Quantity),0) AS TotalOut
FROM PM LEFT OUTER JOIN
PMOutput ON PM.PM_code = PMOutput.PM_code
WHERE (PMOutput.Output_Date BETWEEN ‘2013-01-01’ AND ‘2013-08-25’)
GROUP BY PM.PM_Eng_Name
```

When I run this query I got the total output only for the materials that have output transactions during the selected date rang, while I need to generate the total output for all the PM_Eng_Names I have, with the value 0 for the materials that have no output transaction in the selected date range
Note: I got the perfect report when I remove the WHERE clause, but the date is important for my project
Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get correct results, add dates condition into `join` instead of `where` and put `isnull` inside `sum`:

```
select
    PM.PM_Eng_Name,
    sum(isnull(PMOutput.Quantity, 0)) as TotalOut
from PM
    left outer join PMOutput on PM.PM_code = PMOutput.PM_code and PMOutput.Output_Date BETWEEN ‘2013-01-01’ AND ‘2013-08-25’
group by PM.PM_Eng_Name
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that is because the 'outer joined' columns from `PMOutput` contain only null, so they  are filtered by the where clause

what happens with :

```
WHERE PMOutput.Output_Date is null or (PMOutput.Output_Date BETWEEN ‘2013-01-01’ AND ‘2013-08-25’)
```

Answer (score 0):

`FROM` is one of the initial logic query phases and is completed before `WHERE` is applied.
When `WHERE` is applied in your query it is filtering out lots of rows as they have Output_Date that is `null`.

So initially your LEFT JOIN does this:

```
CREATE TABLE #j 
    (
    Name char(8)
    );
GO
INSERT INTO #j 
    values 
    ('jim'),
    ('michael'),
    ('raj'),
    ('jason'),
    ('tim');
GO

CREATE TABLE #q 
    (
    name char(8), 
    dateBirth datetime
    );
GO
INSERT INTO #q
    values 
    ('jim', '01 jan 2010'),
    ('michael', '01 sep 2010');
GO
```

SELECT  *
FROM    #j
        LEFT OUTER JOIN #q ON
          #j.Name = #q.Name;

This returns the following:

[image]

SQL-server treats `NULL` differently depending which phase of the query it finds the nulls and which operator is applied to the nulls. In the `WHERE` cluse we can see that it discards the rows with null DateBirth if we specify a filter on this attribute:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    #j
        LEFT OUTER JOIN #q ON
        #j.Name = #q.Name
WHERE   dateBirth BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2020-01-01';
```

Results in:

[image]

("Logical Query Phases" would be a good Google)